# Copy associated records to new tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four tables - `company_targetables`, `employee_targetables`, `employees` and `users`. I'm using Postgresql 9.6.

Schema:

`company_targetables`

- `id`
- `company_id` foreign key
- `name` string
- `value` - string

`employee_targetables`

- `id`
- `company_targetable_id` foreign key
- `employee_id` foreign key

`employees`
  - `user_id`

`employee_targetables` is a join between `company_targetables` and `employees`.

I want to move `company_targetables` and `employee_targetables` over to new tables `custom_attributes` and `user_custom_attributes` respectively, preserving the relations, but instead of associating `user_custom_attributes` with an employee, I want to associate it with a `user` record with a `user_id` foreign key.

Schema for new tables:

`custom_attributes`:

- same as schema for `company_targetables`

`user_custom_attributes`

- `custom_attribute_id`
- `user_id` need to grab the user ID from the associate `employee` record from the old table

For example, if I have an `employee_targetable` associated to `company_targetable` with ID 1, I can easily copy the `company_targetable_id`, but I would need to ensure that the corresponding `custom_attribute` record is created with the same values as `company_targetable` so that the column values in the relationship are preserved. Also, I want to make sure the new `user_custom_attribute` record fills in the `user_id` column with the `employees.user_id` value.

Currently, I am doing this 1 by 1 - first creating the `custom_attribute` record and then grabbing the `user_id` off `employee` and creating the `user_custom_attribute` record, but with around 500,000 records, this takes a while.

Is there a way to efficiently do this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You haven't stated that any values are changed between the new and old tables. So why can't you just create the new `custom_attributes` table, do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM company_targetable_id`, then do the same for the `user_custom_attributes` table? The referenced ids will remain the same between all the tables so you're effectively just renaming the tables in a roundabout way. Or is there more to it?

Comment: yes, there is a value changing and I should have outlined it - we're changing the `employee_id` association in `employee_targetables` to `user_id` in `user_custom_attributes`. So instead of referencing an employee record, I need to reference a user record (employees are associated to users with a `user_id` column on the employees table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with

First copy over everything from company_targetables to custom_attributes:

```
      INSERT INTO custom_attributes(id, name, value, targetable, company_id, created_at, updated_at)
  SELECT company_targetables.id, company_targetables.name, company_targetables.value, 't',
         company_targetables.company_id, company_targetables.created_at, company_targetables.updated_at
  FROM company_targetables
```

And then everything from employee_targetables into user_custom_attributes, joining on employees so I can fill in the `user_id` column:

```
      INSERT INTO user_custom_attributes(id, custom_attribute_id, user_id, created_at, updated_at)
  SELECT employee_targetables.id, employee_targetables.company_targetable_id, employees.user_id,
         employee_targetables.created_at, employee_targetables.updated_at
  FROM employee_targetables
  INNER JOIN employees ON employees.id = employee_targetables.employee_id
```

Took 22 seconds for around 500,000 records - there's probably a good way to batch the updates too.